# F:\Android\...: Error: Can't determine type for tag '<item name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</item>

Tags: android

I made the dimensionValues.xml file for keeping all the dimension values.Right now, it has three items.I used these items names/values in some activity pages.I don't know why the android studio can't recognize these items although I provided the correct syntax for it.The same works for color.xml, string.xml files and studio can recognize their values/items. I could not und[enter image description here][1]erstand why it does not identify the values.P.S I am entirely new in Android learning. I hope no one gives me a negative vote even if it is a straightforward question. I could not find an excellent direct solution for it.

```
<--Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. this is in the dimensionValues.xml file-->
    <item name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</item>
    <item name="activity_vertical_margin">24dp</item>

<-- this is how I am trying to catch the values, it is written in an activity page -->
android:paddingBottom="@dimensionValues/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimensionValues/activity_horizontal_margin"
<-- this is the error I am facing-->
Error: Can't determine type for tag '<item name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</item>'


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEEkR.png
```

Answer (score 0):

**In XML file you can not use capital letters for file name**.

Replace your `dimensionValues.xml` file name with `dimension_values.xml`

Comment: Leave comment if any issue with this!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using latest material implementation. I reused the below
code and it worked for me and solved the problem

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
```